# If I have a NAT instance on my AWS console how can i find instances in my account using it for accessing internet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, nat

I have a NAT instance. I will be rebooting it, since I am new to this project i am not sure which instances are using this NAT to access internet. How can I find those instances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Find all VPC route tables that use the NAT instance as a route (usually as the default route, but possibly a more specific route).  The destination of the route table entry will show the instance ID and its primary Elastic Network Interface (ENI) ID.
2. Find all VPC subnets using the route tables identified in step 1.
3. All machines and Lambda functions on any of the subnets identified in Step 2 are using the NAT instance to access the Internet.